# How to pass data down multiple layers of knockout components

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a situation where I am trying to wrap some repeated code into components.  This works fine until I want to pass some data from a parent scope to a component which has been nested within multiple other components.

In my example, I want to be able to get the someobservable value which is in the top level scope all the way down to the myrow component to be displayed within a span. Ideally I don't want to have to pass the data all the way down manually each time, is there a way that the data can just inherit from the parent?

top level scope with my two new components nested within each other

```
<mygroup>
    <myrow>
        <span data-bind="text: someobservable()"></span>
    </myrow>
</mygroup>
```

I can get it to do what I want to by addding `$context.$parentContext.$parent.` before the object, but ideally I don't want to have to do this as it makes everything quite messy.

```
<mygroup>
    <myrow>
        <span data-bind="text: context.$parentContext.$parent.someobservable()"></span>
    </myrow>
</mygroup>
```

**mygroup.js - my first component**

```
import template from './mygroup.html';
const ko = require('knockout');

const viewModel = function (params) {
    const self = this;
};

ko.components.register('mygroup', { viewModel, template });
```

**mygroup.html**

```
<div>
    <!-- ko template: { nodes: $componentTemplateNodes } --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

**myrow.js - my second component**

```
import template from './myrow.html';
const ko = require('knockout');

const viewModel = function (params) {
    const self = this;
};

ko.components.register('myrow', { viewModel, template });
```

**myrow.html**

```
<div>
    <!-- ko template: { nodes: $componentTemplateNodes } --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution where I am semi happy with the results, if anyone can come up with a better solution I would love to hear it though.

```
<mygroup params="data: $data">
    <myrow params="data: $data">
        <span data-bind="text: someobservable()"></span>
    </myrow>
</mygroup>
```

mygroup.js - my first component

```
import template from './mygroup.html';
const ko = require('knockout');

const viewModel = function (params) {
    const self = this;
    this.data = ko.observable(params.data);
};

ko.components.register('mygroup', { viewModel, template });
```

mygroup.html

```
<div>
    <!-- ko template: { nodes: $componentTemplateNodes, data: data } --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

myrow.js - my second component

```
import template from './myrow.html';
const ko = require('knockout');

const viewModel = function (params) {
    const self = this;
    this.data = ko.observable(params.data);
};

ko.components.register('myrow', { viewModel, template });
```

**myrow.html**

```
<div>
    <!-- ko template: { nodes: $componentTemplateNodes, data: data } --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```